# Making multiple turtles in one window

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to make more than two turtles when I run the modules.
So I declared two variables on turtle but there's only one turtle I can see.
What's wrong with my code?

```
import turtle
t1=turtle.Turtle()
t2=turtle.Turtle()

colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]
turtle.bgcolor("yellow")
t1.speed(3)
t1.width(5)
length1 = 10
t2.speed(3)
t2.width(5)
length2 = 10

while length1 < 500:
    t1.fd(length1)
    t1.pencolor(colors[length1%3])
    t1.right (89)
    length1 += 3 #length1 = length1 + 3

while length2 < 500:
    t2.fd(length2)
    t2.pencolor(pink)
    t2.left (89)
    length2 += 4 #length2 = length2 + 4

input()
```

Comment: Python and Turtle is not multitasking. To do two things at the same time (ie. run two turtles at the same time) you would have to use module threading. But I'm not sure if Turtle is "thread-safe". You could try `turtle.ontimer()` to simulate multitasking. Or put both turtles in one `while` loop and make one step with `t1`, then one step with `t2` then again one step with `t1` and again one step with `t2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your turtles are moving one by one. The first `while` loop does the job with `t1`, and when it's done, the second `while` will take care of `t2`. It's like "`t1`, make your first step. Then, `t1`, make your second. (and repeat this until `length1` isn't less than 500 anymore.) Now `t1` is done, so `t2`, make your first step. `t2`, your second step. (and it continues.)"

Instead, you want them to take turns making each of their steps. That's like "`t1`, make your first step. Then, `t2`, make your first. `t1`, make your second step. `t2`, your turn for your second step. (and it continues.)"

So your `while` loop should look like:

```py
t1.pencolor(colors[length1 % 3])
t2.pencolor("pink")

while length1 < 500 or length2 < 500:
    if length1 < 500:
        t1.fd(length1)
        t1.right(89)
        length1 += 3  # length1 = length1 + 3
    if length2 < 500:
        t2.fd(length2)
        t2.left(89)
        length2 += 4  # length2 = length2 + 4
```

(Note you don't have to set the pencolor each time you move the turtle.)

Answer (score 1):

> there's only one turtle I can see

Is there literally only one turtle, or do you run out of patience waiting for the first turtle to finish before the second turtle starts (and breaks, due to the unquoted 'pink')?  If this is about wanting to see both turtles in action at the same time, as folks have concluded, here's my approach:

Short of using threads, I use generators to allow the two turtles to run in a coroutine-like fashion.  The advantage is that the turtles can share the *exact* same code, if they want to, or they can use completely *different* code.  But it avoids *duplicating* code or maintaining *unrelated* code in the same `while` loop:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("yellow")

t1 = Turtle()
t1.pencolor('blue')

t2 = Turtle()
t2.pencolor('pink')

def pattern(turtle, increment, angle):
    turtle.speed('fast')
    turtle.width(5)
    length = 10

    while length < 500:
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.right(angle)
        length += increment
        yield 0

generator1 = pattern(t1, 3, 89)
generator2 = pattern(t2, 4, -89)

while next(generator1, 1) + next(generator2, 1) < 2:
    pass

screen.exitonclick()
```